# Translate Value to Name SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables

[image: Currency Description]

[image: Spot Rates]

Instead of `Currency1Id` and `Currency2Id`, I want to show the `CurrencyShortcut` just to make it look better

In any case I managed to join only one of the fields like this :

[image]

Please help me convert both of them to the values for the currency table

Thanks !!

Comment: When looking at your second table, I think you don't to want to use a separate table unless their is need for relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is something like this

```
SELECT c1.CurrencyShortcut [Currency1], c2.CurrencyShortcut [Currency2] 
    /*, other columns you need*/
FROM Spot as s
    JOIN Currencies as c1 ON s.CurrencyId = c1.CurrencyId
    JOIN Currencies as c2 ON s.CurrencyId = c2.CurrencyId
```

Comment: can you please explain what is this c1 you use , is that a variable or some thing like that ? it gives me an error when I try to do this. can you explain a little more ( sorry I'm really new to SQL )

Comment: @Light_User They are called an [ALIAS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for the table. SQL server doesn't require using the `AS` keyword but some databases do. They are used to reduce typing the full table name.

Comment: @Light_User What is your database and what is the error you get?

Comment: Thank you, it took me awhile to get it :) works like magic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can alias your columns too..

```
SELECT 
     c1.Currency1Id     AS Currency1Shortcut
     , c2.Currency2Id   AS Currency2Shortcut
```